# Each time same object is persisted using JPA a new row is inserted in database

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Having this class annotated with `javax.persistence.*` annotations:

```
@Entity
public class Car{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private Integer weight;

    public setWeight(weight) {
        this.weight = weight
    }
    
    public Integer getWeight() {
        return this.weight;
    }
}
```

When saved an object X of this class in Database using Spring `JpaRepository` interface `save(S entity)` method, it is generated an Id for this object and saved in Database.

But then, if the object X state changes and it is saved again using the `save(S entity)` method it is not updated the old row in Database but a new row is created. I guess this behaviour is because the object id was not updated after been autogenerated the first save message returns (it seems it is needed a flush operation between).

So this is not working:

```
Car myCar = new Car();
carJPARepository.save(myCar); --> New row in Database is inserted;
myCar.setWeight(Integer.valueOf(1000));
carJPARepository.save(myCar); --> New row is inserted in Database instead updated the first one
```

By the way the documentation for `save(S entity)` method says:

> Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely.

Does it mean the object we pass as parameter to save method is a different object that the one it is returned, with possibly a different state?

Comment: Assign the return value of the `save` method to `myCar` to get the managed instance. You are probably running this in a non transactional test method leading to a detached instance instead of the reusing of a persisted one.

Comment: could you the post the controller and service code ?

Comment: @M.Deinum That _shouldn't_ be necessary using JPA repositories specifically; the correct solution is to fix the transactionality.

Comment: I have annotated the class using JPARepository with org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional annotation and still the object has id = 0 after save message return.. but the object returned by the save method is different object (and this object has the right id set)

Comment: persist, update, find, delete are the autogen methods for JPA if I recall correctly.  If your save() method is calling persist() it's going to create a new row every time unless there is some kind of logic checking the ID in the entity for !=null and calling update(id)

Comment: Doesn't matter if your save method is transactional. The method that has this code needs to be transactional. Currently you have 2 individual calls to save which both are transactional (i.e. start each their own transaction).

Comment: So the solution is not to add the transaction annotation to the service using  the jpaRepository right? Because it does not work... The solution is to work with the object returned by save method cause it is the one managed by the ORM..

Answer (score 1):

```java
Car myCar = new Car();
myCar = carJPARepository.save(myCar); // get the Car object with update id
myCar.setWeight(Integer.valueOf(1000));
carJPARepository.save(myCar); // calling save will now update as java object as the id
```

Comment: It does not work, when performing (in same method body):
Car myCar = new Car();
carJPARepository.save(myCar); 
myCar.setWeight(1000); --> Here myCar still has not the new id set

Comment: Also generally making your `@Controller` `@Transactional is a bad idea, the service layer should be the transactional boundary not your web layer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please follow my example to get simple understanding of the flow.
Before `save` the instance is not managed by after that it is. Hence all the changes made to the entity will qualify for the update operation.

when you hit the `dirty-save` endpoint, you should see logs similar to below:

```
Object before save is not assigned default id value and weight is anyway null
Car(id=null, weight=null)
Hibernate: values next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into car (weight, id) values (?, ?)
Plain saved object with default value
Car(id=1, weight=null)
Hibernate: update car set weight=? where id=?
Object with updated weight field
Car(id=1, weight=1000)
```

As you can see, when you set the weight to 1000 this time it is consider to update instead of creating new record.

```java
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cars")
public class CarController {

    private final CarService carService;

    @Autowired
    public CarController(CarService carService) {
        this.carService = carService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<Car> cars() {
        return carService.cars();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Car create(@RequestBody Car car) {
        return carService.save(car);
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "dirty-save")
    public Car dirtyCreate() {
        Car myCar = new Car();
        System.out.println("Object before save is not assigned default id value and weight is anyway null");
        System.out.println(myCar);
        carService.save(myCar);
        System.out.println("Plain saved object with default value");
        System.out.println(myCar);
        myCar.setWeight(1000);
        carService.save(myCar);
        System.out.println("Object with updated weight field");
        System.out.println(myCar);
        return myCar;
    }


}

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private Integer weight;
}

@Service
class CarService {
    private final CarRepository carRepository;

    @Autowired
    CarService(CarRepository carRepository) {
        this.carRepository = carRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Car save(Car car) {
        return carRepository.save(car);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Iterable<Car> cars() {
        return carRepository.findAll();
    }
}

@Repository
interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Integer> {
}
```